# Organization of fuzzy matches

Tags: python, fuzzy-comparison

I've gone through and fuzzy matched each element in a list of 20,000+ movie titles with each other element, which returns a value for each pair:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

titles = ['Scary Movie', 'Happy Movie', 'Sappy Movie', 'Crappy Movie']

print fuzz.ratio(titles[2],titles[3])
>>> 91 #/100 higher value denotes closer match 

for x in titles:
    for y in titles:
        fuzzed = fuzz.ratio(x,y)

    print "value for %r and %r is %r" % (x, y, fuzzed)
```

How can I organize this data efficiently? More specifically- how can I get matches to group together based on their match value?

Capturing the return values from the nested loops and then packaging them with x and y into tuples or lists is obviously redundant and messy. I attempted an implementation using classes but I'm missing something.

Comment: Does `fuzz.ratio(x, y)` == `fuzz.ratio(y, x)` for all x and y?

Comment: @Navith yes, actually 'ratio' is somewhat of a misnomer, I think it is better described as a match percentage since the return values are 0-100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using list comprehensions and `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
[(x, y, fuzz.ratio(x, y)) for (x, y) in product(titles, repeat=2)]
```

Nice and lazy solution using [`toolz`](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz)

```
from toolz.curried import pipe, filter, map
pipe(
    product(titles, repeat=2),
    # No reason to check duplicates
    filter(lambda (x, y): x > y),
    map(lambda (x, y): (x, y, fuzz.ratio(x, y))))
```

Comment: Accepted answer, thanks- I did amend my question to include this: ...how can I get matches to group together based on their match value and title? (need to account for different matches between titles having the same number value)

Comment: Do you mean grouping like this: `('Crappy Movie', 87) => ('Happy Movie', 'Sappy Movie')`?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to iterate over [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of the titles since the ratio doesn't depend on the order. This is significantly faster than iterating over a [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of it.

For your list of 20,000 titles, you would iterate over **400 000 000** pairs if you used `product`. With `combinations`, you are only iterating over **199 990 000**.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

import collections
import itertools

titles = ['Scary Movie', 'Happy Movie', 'Sappy Movie', 'Crappy Movie']
```

Then you can store the ratios in a dictionary where you can look up a ratio to get a `set` of pairs with that ratio.

```
fuzzes_by_ratio = collections.defaultdict(set)
```

Or in a dictionary where you can look up a `frozenset` of pairs and get their ratio.

```
fuzzes_per_pair = {}
```

-

```
for m1, m2 in itertools.combinations(titles, 2):
    pair = frozenset({m1, m2})
    ratio = fuzz.ratio(m1, m2)

    fuzzes_by_ratio[ratio].add(pair)
    fuzzes_per_pair[pair] = ratio
```

Then you can retrieve the data later:

```
# I don't have fuzzywuzzy installed so this is just made up:
>>> fuzzes_by_ratio[91]
{frozenset({"Scary Movie", "Happy Movie"}), frozenset({"Sappy Movie", "Happy Movie"})}

>>> fuzz_per_pair[frozenset({"Scary Movie", "Sappy Movie"})]
82
```

Keep in mind that you will need tons of memory for this storage. You can halve it by using only one of the two methods above, depending on your needs / convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can store the `fuzzed` ratio in a dictionary with the `(x,y)` tuple as the key, would make it easier to search the `ratio` for each pair later on. For that you can create an empty dictionary outside the for loop , and then in for loop assign the `fuzz.ratio(x , y)` to the key `(x, y)` for that dictionary.

Example code -

```
fuzzDict = {}
for x in titles:
    for y in titles:
        fuzzDict[(x,y)] = fuzz.ratio(x,y)
```

Later when you want to retrieve the ratio, you can simple call `fuzzDict[(x , y)]` to get it.

---

You can also use dictionary comprehension for that in Python 2.7+ -

```
{(x, y) : fuzz.ratio(x,y) for x in titles for y in titles}
```